# Connect old laptop LCD to RPi

Tags: pi-3, screen, laptop, lcd

I have an old laptop and I was wondering if I could take the LCD from it and use it with my RPi 3, the end goal is to make an RPi laptop complete with a 3D printed case, so would this LCD connection be possible?

Let me know what info you guys need.

Comment: No you can not (unless you want to spend hundreds of pounds to end up with a product which is worse than what you could have bought off the shelf new).

Comment: https://youtu.be/r0IiXl88Sfw

Comment: There are many ways to do this, but you will have to order specific components from ebay that relate to your laptop's display. I suggest watching the video above, but also doing more research

Comment: Although this is not exactly the same question, it is a variation on a theme...have a look through the duplicate chain.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, you can use [M.NT68676.2A](https://www.ebay.com/itm/M-NT68676-2A-HDMI-DVI-VGA-Audio-LCD-Controller-Board-DIY-Kit-Power-Adapter-/121059321784) or [another](https://www.amazon.co.uk/M-NT68676-2A-Controller-Monitor-remember-placing/dp/B00KVDS2NI) to connect your LCD to your raspberry pi.

The kit replace screen controller of lambda computer screen like Samsung, BenQ, Phillips and other. You have just to put the connector of your screen on the kit.

[Like thi documentation](http://www.vslcd.com/Specification/M.NT68676.2A.pdf)

And when you have finish you can connect your raspberry by using HDMI

Comment: Could you please acknowledge your affiliation with the product, otherwise your answer could be considered an advert. Also link-only answers are highly discouraged please edit your answer to include some kind of explanation. As noted in the comments on the question more information is required from the OP to accurately answer their question.