# Using my old laptop as an external monitor

Tags: display, laptop

I have been looking round to see if there is a solution for this question, but in vain. Please don't blame me if there is.

So I have got a broken Dell Vostro 14-5480. Its monitor has no problems at all, but I don't want to dissemble it to make an external monitor. The problem with it that makes it broken is the hard-drive. It kept failing and failing. I have changed 5 HDDs and 1 SSD within 1.5 years and it is still happening and I have completely lost hope. Therefore I am thinking of recycling the laptop so I can use it as an external display

As I understand, laptops are not meant to accept display, and I know with my current laptop if I connect both with an hdmi cable it will not work. Are there any ways to use the Dell Vostro 14-5480 screen as an extended display with my current laptop without dissembling it? Thanks!

Comment: This is (old but) related https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/848/19949 in short: *you'll have to find an LCD controller that supports your panel.*

Comment: Welcome -- see also this long chain of duplicates: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/76129/5538 My usual comment is anyone with the skills to do this would probably not consider it worth their time -- which is why many people have asked but almost no one seems to have reached the goal.

Comment: you could boot a linux distribution from a flash drive .... then you could display web pages that are served up by your RPi